# Hidden aria labels in HTML table (for screen reader accessibility)

Tags: html, css, html-table, accessibility, wai-aria

In my webpage, I need to create a table which has a header row which is visible or hidden according to some user configuration. This table also needs to be fully accessible (specifically, since the table can be very long, I would like that shortcuts that **read the row/column headers would work**). I only have ChromeVox to test with (I'll detail about behaviors with other readers from blog-posts I found).

My current layout looks similar to this one:

CSS:

```
.table-header-show {
}

.table-header-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <!-- ${show} is used to choose the right class the user configuration -->
  <thead class="table-header-${show}">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Value 1a</td>
      <td>Value 2a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When the header is visible, there is no problem at all. When the header is hidden, it depends on the screen reader whether these labels are read out or not:

- I would like the **header row to be skipped when using regular navigation*** with the screen reader, but **use the header row to announce column labels**
- With ChromeVox, the first works (skipped in navigation) but the second fails (the hidden row is not used to label columns)
- Again with ChromeVox, moving the hiding to be declared as a`style` attribute rather than a `class`, cause both desired behaviors to work
- According to a blog post I found, [screen readers somtimes ignore `display: none`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/screen_readers_sometimes_ignore_displaynone/) in order to speak out content, and sometimes they do not - so I'm not sure I can rely on this sort of hiding to be reliable for my purpose (hide for navigation, use for labeling)

So, how can I achieve my desired behavior in a cross-browser-reader way?

- AFAIK, the problem with off-screen/1px-sized hiding (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269670/when-should-a-hidden-element-be-available-to-a-screen-reader-for-accessibilit)) is that if I do this for the header row, then all the column headers would always be read out...

Comment: Have you tried adding header row at run time in JS in document.ready() on the basis of value of ${show}

Comment: FWIW, I suspect offscreen/1px will be your best and most reliable bet here: the catch is that otherwise you're asking the screenreader to do two contradictory things: to *ignore* the heading when navigating, but to *respect* the heading when looking for headers. As I understand how screenreaders generally work, they'll either treat it as being there, or not being there, but not this type of "both". It does mean that screenreader users will get to navigate an extra 'invisible' row that sighted users don't see, but that's a lesser problem (and perhaps useful context) than no labels.

Comment: Bonus accessibility tip(s): in tables like this, it's good to make the initial cell in each row a TH also - even if you style it to look like a regular TD: this allows a user to navigate down through other columns and have the initial name column read out as they navigate rows. Also, place scope="col" on the top THs and scope="row" on the left THs; some screenreader/browser combinations will do odd things without this.

Answer (score 3):

The most fool proof option will be to hide the header rows from the screen reader, either by removing them from the DOM (preferred) or with a screen-reader safe removal. Then insert the header into each applicable cell with `text-indent: -999em;` or similar visual hiding that preserves screen reader access.

This is a very unsatisfying answer, but it should be tenable with the jquery. Roughly: for each `th`, store content in an array, then select each td in the applicable column, and `.prependTo()` the 'th'.

Again, very unsatisfying and messy but the only fool proof solution I can think of. Best of luck.

Comment: I was afraid of this sort of answer, as this doesn't work exactly right; adding labels like that to each cell will mean they will always be read out, without the option to silence them. You don't need to hear the column names on every row, but you may want to check it for the first few...

Comment: Yeah, my only other thoughts are more out-of-the-box ideas. Could this data be provided outside of a table? "John Doe has value 1a and value 2a" Maybe you could concatenate each record with a few prepositions/linking verbs?

Answer (score 2):

It won't hurt to use aria-hidden="false" if  ChromeVox is currently your only concern. You can use it preferably in combination with the HTML5 hidden attribute (see example below) but other techniques might work as well. See [**this article**](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/hidden2013.html) from late 2013 for compatibility of the different techniques. If compatibility is a concern, the off screen method seems to be the way to go.

#### Off screen method:

```
<style>
    thead {
        position:absolute;
        left:-9999px
    }
</style>
```

#### Hidden method:

```
<table>
  <!-- ${show} is used to choose the right class the user configuration -->
  <thead hidden aria-hidden="false">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>Value 1a</td>
      <td>Value 2a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value 1</th>
                    <th id="foo">Value 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John Doe</td>
                    <td>Value 1a</td>
                    <td id="foo">Value 2a</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


#foo {
        visibility: collapse
    }
```

But About above mention code don't have all browser support.

To improve what you have, you could use `table-layout: fixed` on table because of table- layout when table-cell is not `display: none` it will automatically `display: table-cell`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment (I don't want to collapse a column, I want to collapse a row). Anyway, I tried playing with `visibility: collapse` (I shrunk the height of my row to 1px and removed `display: none`) but it didn't work well - The screen reader did navigate through the collapsed cells (saying they were empty) and additionally it did not use them as column labels.
But thanks for suggesting this!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `display: none` on the head - try moving off-screen by taking it out of the flow - something like:

```
<table class="hidden-header">
    ...

.hidden-header thead {
    display: absolute;
    left: -9999
}
```

I have not tested this ... but might work.

### Edit: Further reading:

A quick google game me the following articles i recommend:

- http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/
- http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/
- http://alistapart.com/article/now-you-see-me (though has javascript, not just css)
- http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/ (lots more links, Chris has researched this a lot)

Why don't you send this as a question to the ShopTalk Show popcast for one of their quick-fire episodes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it won't work since AFAIK navigation in screen readers is based on the DOM and not on the visible arrangement (that's what I remember from the code of the open source ones, I even wrote this at the end of my question). I'll check again tomorrow at work, maybe I'm wrong here

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in the answer here as well, and I hope I understand the question. What if you use `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags and give them an `aria-label`? ChromeVox reads them and they are semantically tied to the columns.

Here's an example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j87x7sn5/4/

This code uses sibling selectors to "hide" the colgroups when the header is visible and "show" them when it is not so the screenreader doesn't read it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Display None what if use opacity 0 ,

i tried to Google this for any clear answer but didn't get any clear one but still i can assume Screen Reader ignore opacity and read Table Labels as normal and its not visible for Normal Users.